# Issue with resolving promises in Objective-C native module

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, sockets, objective-c-category

I'm working on integrating a native module written in Objective-C into a React Native project. The module, called SocketModule, provides socket communication functionality. I'm encountering an issue with resolving promises in the checkForPackage method.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
/**
* Checks for any available package.
*
* @param resolve The callback function called when a package is found.
* @param reject The callback function called when an error occurs.
*
* @discussion This function checks if there is any available package to 
* read. It reads the buffer and logs its contents before resolving the 
* promise.
* If an exception occurs, it rejects the promise with an error status.
*/ 


// SocketModule.h

@interface SocketModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTPromiseResolveBlock packagesResolver;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GCDAsyncSocket *socket;

@end

@implementation SocketModule

// ...

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkForPackage:(nonnull RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(nonnull                    RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    self.packagesResolver = resolve;
    @try {
        NSData *data;
        NSLog(@"Data start");

        [self.socket readDataToData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
        reject(@"Exception", exception.reason, nil);
    }
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(nonnull NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data received: %@", message);
    self.packagesResolver(message)
}

// ...

@end
```

The issue I'm facing is related to resolving promises in the checkForPackage method. The first time the method is called, it successfully assigns the resolve parameter to the packagesResolver property and invokes didReadData, which logs the received data and resolves the promise using self.packagesResolver(message).

However, when the checkForPackage method is called for the second time, didReadData is also invoked but doesn't logs the received data, but it doesn't seem to resolve the promise correctly the first time.

I'm not sure why the promise is not being resolved in subsequent calls to checkForPackage. Could it be related to how promises are handled in Objective-C or the lifecycle of the packagesResolver property? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue.

I suspect that there may be a problem with how promises are handled in Objective-C or with the lifecycle of the packagesResolver property. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue and ensure that the checkForPackage method can read data every time it is called and resolve the promise with the received data.

Output:

```
[trickstertussle] Data start
[trickstertussle] Data received: {"signal": 58}
[trickstertussle] Data start
```